# javascript syntax for passing variables to function

Tags: javascript, syntax, hyperlink

I have a JavaScript hyperlink that is not passing variable to function, undoubtedly due to syntax. Can someone please spot error.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kSVVX/

js

```
function follow(id){
    alert(id);
}
```

html

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick= 'follow('1');'><img src='images/test.gif' border=0 alt='follow'></a>
```

Note:  The reason that I am using all apostrophes is that this link is actually getting echoed from php where a long string is enclosed in quote marks (as certain things in the string must be in apostrophes.)  I have a feeling this is source of problem, but have not succeeded in solving it by changing punctuation around.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: *javascript syntax in php*? How is the related to PHP?

Comment: title edited.  I meant it was being echoed in php using quotes, however, you are correct this is not about php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `'` characters to delimit your JavaScript string **and** the HTML attribute value it is embedded in.

This results in:

```
onclick= 'follow('
```

Either:

- Avoid intrinsic event attributes (which you should be doing anyway, [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) is recommended).
- Use different characters to delimit the attribute value (`onclick="follow('1');"`) or string (`onclick= 'follow("1");'`)
- Use HTML entities to include the quote mark you are using in the data for the attribute value (`onclick= 'follow(&#39;1&#39;);'`)

Comment: this is all inside a php echo statement delimited with quotes so if I employ quotes, I interfere with that statement.  I guess the html approach will work...I don't suppose there a way to escape the apostrophes in some way or use backicks?

Comment: @user1260310 — PHP has syntax for escaping quote characters in strings … but nesting languages inside each other is a good way to get ugly, hard to maintain code. The top option on the list of solutions is at the top for a reason. Don't use intrinsic event attributes. Do use external JavaScript. Don't put HTML in PHP strings. Do drop out of PHP mode (`?>`) or use a template language to output HTML.

Comment: I changed the jsfiddle to quotes but there still seems to be something wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/kSVVX/2/

Comment: @user1260310 — You are wrapping the script in an onload function, so your function is scoped to that function. Set "no wrap" in the jsfiddle options.